# How can my code be injected with SQL injection?

Tags: sql, database, security, sql-injection, payload

I have the following code running for logging in.

```
M_INVALID_PASSWORD_OR_USERNAME_2 SELECT `s1_members`.* FROM `s1_members` 
WHERE (`password` LIKE '5bd7002ef05124e82000bb83d83455ec8c50a1e8') AND 
(email LIKE 'test@tefrfrfwfe.frrfr' OR phone LIKE 'test@tefrfrfwfe.frrfr')"
```

I know my email/phone seem to be vulnerable, but I am escaping singled quotes by adding two backlashes (\) before each single quote. The double quotes get escaped by adding three backlashes beforehead (\). I also escape backslash by adding three more backslashes after (\).

I am still a learning in this field, so want to know in what ways/payloads then can an attacker inject an SQL injection? If there are payloads that will be executable here, then how do I protect myself?

I have tried different kinds of SQL injections I could find on Internet and seems that my special character escaping is working fine. I know it's not ideal though, so want to know what type of payloads of SQL injection can be successfully executed in my code.

Comment: Use parameters rather than manually inserting your values into the SQL

Comment: Are you reinventing the wheel, or trying to learn about how the wheel was invented? As  @rory.ap said, you should let the library or driver you're using handle this rather than doing it yourself. If you're trying to understand what it does, you should review the library code.

Comment: "In what way" depends on your database engine -- they all handle quoting, escaping and statement batches somewhat differently. An attacker has all the time and motivation to try different things until something works. Using parameterized statements prevents all shenanigans and is the safer choice over trying to find vulnerabilities in your quoting setup (unless you *are* the attacker, of course).

Comment: Without looking at your code, it's impossible to say, what your "adding slashes look like" and whether it's safe or not. Moreover, it's justunclear, why would you bother adding all those slashes instead of using a proper solution. That makes your question off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements (aka parameterized queries).  When using prepared statements the parameters are never interpreted as SQL, they're simply processed by the database as data.

The escaping technique you're using, even if it works, is fragile.  It is dependent on the client language, how the string is composed on the client, and which database you're using.

A couple of things that could go wrong:

- The string on the client could have a fixed length - the encoding mechanism can be manipulated by the hacker to overrun that length.  That can be used to truncate off key parts of the query or create buffer overflows.
- The slashes may be interpreted by the client language as well, switching the client context might change the number of slashes required.
- The database might change - either because the code is used with a different database or the behavior changes on upgrade.  As mentioned by Jeroen in the comments, databases all handle encoding differently.

Comment: Where did you get that "client" notion tho?